# ImportError in rest_framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, importerror, django-serializer

I am designing a REST API with the class_name as employees. But when I import it in serializers section it is showing me an ImportError. I think there's something I am dong wrong in urls.py or settings.py file. But I am not sure. Can anyone please get some solutions??

```
>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Projects\Django\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\Projects\Django\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)      
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "G:\Projects\Django\Django\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    from RESTapp import views
  File "G:\Projects\Django\RESTapp\serializers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework import employees
ImportError: cannot import name 'employees' from 'rest_framework' (C:\Users\USER\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\__init__.py)
```

Thank You in advance!!

Comment: Hi. Please also paste the Code that is producing this errors.

Answer (score 0):

`ImportError: cannot import name 'employees' from 'rest_framework'`

Django REST Framework is missing employee name file/package. So you are trying to import from the wrong place